# XSD using defined complex type within same file

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got the following XSD file (the relevant bits):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://somenamespace"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="UserType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="id" type="int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="registrationDate" type="date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="email" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="name" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="surname" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="UserListType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="userList" type="tns:UserType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

The problem I'm having is that this isn't valid. When I try to validate the XSD online I get this error: `Cannot resolve tns:UserType as a QName, the prefix tns is not declared`.

As far as I understand, `tns` refers to "this namespace" and I need to use it here since I've defined the global namespace as the XMLSchema in the schema tag. It must be some minor oversight, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there isn´t any predefined `tns` namespace in w3c schema, so you must add the `xmlns:tns="http://somenamespace"` to your schema tag.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that fixed it.